# How to access token additionalInformation to validate expression-based access control

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

I succesfully added `user_id` additionnal information on the generated tokens on the authorization server side by implementing a `TokenEnhancer`. Here is a token generated:

`{"access_token":"ccae1713-00d4-49c2-adbf-e699c525d53e","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":31512,"scope":"end-user","user_id":2}`

Now, on the Resource server side, which is a completely separate spring project communicating through a `RemoteTokenServices`, i would like to use theses informations with method `expression-based access control`. For example i would like to use the added `user_id` data (it is Spring Data JPA repository for use with Spring Data Rest):

`@PreAuthorize("#oauth2.hasScope('admin') or #id == authentication.principal.user_id")
@Override
UserAccount findOne (@P("id") Integer id);`

The `#oauth2.hasScope('admin')` works as expected but the `#id == authentication.principal.user_id"` part obviously not.

how can i access to the additional data added to the token on expression-based access control ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So i've found myself. The key interface is `UserAuthenticationConverter`.

Using the default provided `DefaultUserAuthenticationConverter` class, we can set a `UserDetailsService` which is used to set `authentication.principal` with the UserDetail object returned by the UserDetailsService. Without that, authentication.principal is only set with the token username as a String.

Here is an extract of my `ResourceServerConfigAdapter`:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration 
        extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService () {
        return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserAuthenticationConverter userAuthenticationConverter () {
        DefaultUserAuthenticationConverter duac 
            = new DefaultUserAuthenticationConverter();
        duac.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        return duac;
    }

    @Bean
    public AccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        DefaultAccessTokenConverter datc 
            = new DefaultAccessTokenConverter();
        datc.setUserTokenConverter(userAuthenticationConverter());
        return datc;
    }

    @Bean
    RemoteTokenServices getRemoteTokenServices () {
        RemoteTokenServices rts = new RemoteTokenServices();
        rts.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl(
            "http://localhost:15574/oauth/check_token");
        rts.setAccessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter());
        rts.setClientId("client");
        rts.setClientSecret("pass");
        return rts;
    }

    ...

}
```

Another method is to override the DefaultUserAuthenticationManager and provide a custom `public Authentication extractAuthentication(Map<String, ?> map)`.

Once this is done, we can use the user data on `expression-based access control` like that:

```
@PreAuthorize("#oauth2.hasScope('admin') or #id == authentication.principal.userAccount.id")
@Override
UserAccount findOne (@P("id") Integer id);
```

Note that `userAccount` is my original DOMAIN user object. It could be everything the UserDetailsService returns.

**EDIT:**
To answer to Valentin Despa, here is my UserDetailsService implementation:

```java
@Component
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserAccountRepository userAccountRepository;

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername (String username) 
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        // Fetch user from repository
        UserAccount ua = this.userAccountRepository
            .findByEmail(username);

        // If nothing throws Exception
        if (ua == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
                "No user found having this username");
        }

        // Convert it to a UserDetails object
        return new UserDetailsImpl(ua);

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. How does your UserDetailsServiceImpl look like?

Comment: I added my UserDetailsServiceImpl to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply.

Comment: Is your resource server and authorization server pointing to same database?

Comment: Thanks @tiben. just implemented the way you suggested, and its working. in my case, the resource server and auth-server are pointing to different database.